# How to show a modal from anoter js file to current file in react-native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, ecmascript-6

I want to show a modal from another js class to current class file.Hoe can i set modal visibility true in current js file,hence my modal code resides in another class.I want to use this code in actual sign up class.Here is my code:-

**CountryCodePicker.js**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet,  Text,  View} from 'react-native'
  import { showMessage } from '../utils/GeneralFunctions';
  import { countryPicker } from './CountryPickerModal';

  export default class CountryCodePicker extends Component {    
      constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      }

    render() {
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text
                  onPress={() => {
                    <countryPicker modalVisible={true}/>
                  }} 
                  style={styles.welcome}>Open Modal</Text>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }


  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      },
      welcome: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 10,
        padding:20
      }
    })
```

**CountryPickerModal**: Here is my modal code that i want to show on country picker class.

```
  import React from 'react';
  import {Modal,View,Text} from 'react-native';
  import { showMessage } from '../utils/GeneralFunctions';

  export const countryPicker = (props) => {
      const {modalVisible = false} = props;

      state = {
          modalVisible:modalVisible
      }

      showModal = () => {
          // if(modalVisible == false){
          //     modalVisible = true;
          // }else{
          //     modalVisible=false;
          // }

          this.setState({modalVisible:true});
      }

      return(
          <Modal
              visible={modalVisible}
              animationType='slide'
              transparent={false}
              onRequestClose={() => {showMessage('Closed')}}
          >
          <View>
              <Text 
                  style={{fontSize:24,fontWeight:'900',padding:16}}
                  onPress={() => {showMessage("Country Picker 
                          Modal")}}
              >
                  Close Modal
              </Text>
          </View>
          </Modal>
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define it in `render` and pass flag for visible or hide.

```
render() {
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text
              onPress={() => {
                this.setState({modalVisible:true})
              }} 
              style={styles.welcome}>Open Modal</Text>
          <countryPicker modalVisible={this.state.modalVisible}/>          
      </View>
  );
}
```